# C++ Primer Binary Search not working. Can not understand why

Tags: c++

```
void binary_search_vec(std::vector<int> a, int finder) {    

    auto full_beg = a.begin();
    auto beg = a.begin();
    auto end = a.end();
    auto mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;


    while (*mid != finder && mid != end) {

        if (finder > *mid) {
          beg = mid + 1;

        }
        else {  //(*mid > finder) 


            end = mid;
        }
        mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;

        if (finder == *mid) { // Here is the problem leading to undefined behavior. I am negating the condition in the While Loop. Credit to Bob___ for the fix. And thank you to the community.

         std::cout << "Num found: " << finder << " at position: " << std::distance(full_beg, mid) << 
         std::endl;
         break;
        
        }

    }
    
}
```

Edit:
The code in question is from C++ Primer 5th edition. The binary search in question simply does not return the num found. I Can not understand why. Compared line by line with other users. Theirs work mine does not.

This code from another user works. I do not understand the difference
2nd edit:
@Bob___ fix code:

```
auto full_beg = a.begin();
auto beg = a.begin();
auto end = a.end();
auto mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;


while (*mid != finder && mid != end) {

if (finder > * mid) {
      beg = mid + 1;

    }
    else {  //(*mid > finder) 


        end = mid;
    }
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;

}
 if (finder == *mid) {
    std::cout << "Num found: " << finder << " at position Index: " << std::distance(full_beg, mid) << std::endl;

}
else std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: What should this program do? Looks like you're doing binary search, what is the "Primer" ?

Comment: Please add the code that calls `binary_search_vec` including an example of data that reproduces the problem. Actually we need a [mcve]

Comment: C++ Primer as in the textbook?

Comment: I just did some changes updating the problem in question.

Comment: Well, for starters, you changed the condition in `while` (yours leads to undefined behaviour, BTW).

Comment: If `*mid != finder` is `true` right from the beginning, (e.g you^re looking for 3 in the vector `{1,2,3,4})`, the code inside the while is never executed and nothing is displayed.

Comment: @ Bob__  Provided the Solution and the fix to problem. Will change the post to explain the the solution provided by Bob. Quite the beginner's mistake by my part.

Answer (score 1):

Move the last `if` branch out of the while loop and remove the `break` statement otherwise it won't work if the `finder` is the same as the `mid`.

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void binary_search_vec(std::vector<int> a, int finder) {    

    auto full_beg = a.begin();
    auto beg = a.begin();
    auto end = a.end();
    auto mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;

    std::cout << "MID AT THE BEGINNING: " << *mid << std::endl;
    while (mid != end && *mid != finder) {

        if (finder > *mid) {
          std::cout << "Finder > mid" << std::endl;
          beg = mid + 1;

        }
        else {  //(*mid > finder) 
          std::cout << "Finder > mid" << std::endl;
          end = mid;
        }
        mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
        std::cout << "Setting mid to " << *mid << std::endl;
    }
    
    if (finder == *mid) {
      std::cout << "Num found: " << finder << " at position: " << std::distance(full_beg, mid) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();
  v.push_back(0);
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);

  binary_search_vec(v, 1);
}
```

Using your function, the previous code does not work when `finder = 2`.

Also check the comment from @Bob__: the order of the condition evaluation inside the while is extremely important!

Comment: Just finished updating the solution from  Bob__. Thank you very much for the input too.

Comment: Why declaring the vector 'v' like that `std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();`  what is the difference from doing `std::vector<int> v;` ?

Comment: @Sambalika just style... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix and updated code. Courtesy of Bob___

void binary_search_vec(std::vector a, int finder) {

```
auto full_beg = a.begin();
auto beg = a.begin();
auto end = a.end();
auto mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;


while (*mid != finder && mid != end) {

if (finder > * mid) {
      beg = mid + 1;

    }
    else {  //(*mid > finder) 


        end = mid;
    }
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;

}
 if (finder == *mid) {
    std::cout << "Num found: " << finder << " at position Index: " << std::distance(full_beg, mid) << std::endl;

}
else std::cout << "Not Found!" << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: This does not work if `*mid == finder` from the beginning.

Comment: It works now because if (finder == *mid) is outside the scope of the while loop. No more double negations and undefined behavior.

Comment: mmm nope... it is not :) You have some weird formatting that make everything confusing.. :) And BTW, you just copy pasted my answer... which is not really nice :)

Comment: No. It works. Second @Bob__  Provided th anwser first and i fixed the program. See the comments in the first question. From Bob = Well, for starters, you changed the condition in while (yours leads to undefined behaviour, BTW). – Bob__ 2 hours ago

Comment: I also replied to you with this. Check above.   Just finished updating the solution from Bob__. Thank you very much for the input too. This was to you 2 hours ago. Once again thanks for the support.